# REST call not working for phone, but does work for desktop

Tags: spring, rest, mobile, network-programming, raspberry-pi3

I have a Raspberry Pi (Model 3B I believe) which I have equipped with a simple Spring REST service. The service supports a GET method which is mapped to [HOST]:[PORT]/test/get/. All this method does is return `GET call successful!` immediately after being invoked.

I used `ifconfig` on my Raspberry Pi to get its ip address, and it seems to function fine for the desktop (works in the URL and in Postman). My problem comes in when I try to access the same exact method using my phone. Attached below are images of the two calls. The URL is exactly the same in both calls.

Also, all three devices are connected to the same wifi network.

[image: Desktop REST Call]

[image: Phone REST Call]

Please try to answer why it doesn't function on my phone as opposed to finding a work around. The purpose of me using this very basic GET method is because I have more complex methods that are running into the same issue and they boil down to this obstacle.

Device Details:
Raspberry Pi 3 Model B (Uses wifi)
Desktop with Windows 10
iPhone 6 Plus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I coincidentally found the answer through another person's phone. I'm using the Google Chrome app, but that doesn't come standard on all iPhones, so this person's phone only had Safari. When I tried to access the service using Safari it said:
[image: Safari Call]

Which is way clearer. Upon a google search of what this means, I discovered that port 6000 is one of a number of restricted ports that are reserved for other things. So I changed the REST service to use port 6001 (which I then verified is not a restricted port) and then the service worked in both safari and chrome.

So it was just bad luck that I picked 6000 as my port. I wish Google Chrome would give a more detailed message, would have saved me a lot of time.

NOTE: This answer lists all restricted ports:
https://superuser.com/a/188070/690813